# Synchronous call of external contract function in Solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain

I have two Solidity contracts, where contract `Caller` depends on a second contract `Callee`. Contract `Callee` provides a public view function which checks the validity of a string (e.g. an password), according to some internal rules. `Caller` needs to check a string in its own function by calling `Callee`, before he can further process. Furthermore `Caller` needs to call the function of `Callee` by using `delegatecall`, because the internal validity check considers the calling address.

```
contract Caller {

  function doSomething(string _text, address _callee) public {
     bool valid = bool(_callee.delegatecall(
                          bytes4(keccak256("check(string _text)")), _text)
                  );

     require(valid == true);
     /* further process if text is valid */
  }
}

contract Callee {

  function check(string _text) public view returns(bool){
    /* validity check */
    return true;
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is, that the call of function `check` seems to be asynchronous and therefore the `require` statement in function `doSomething` will always fail. Is this a problem of `delegatecall`? Is there a way to call the external function synchronously?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to my problem: Sadly, one cannot receive values from delegatecall function calls.

Comment: Well, the virtual machine DOES support return values in `DELEGATECALL` opcode :`func opDelegateCall(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error)`

Comment: really? Do I read the opcode correctly: It can return a byte array?

Comment: I am not really expert in writing contracts, but DELGATECALL opcode works  the same way as CALL opcode. I know because I modified the VM for a custom blockchain processing. It is absolutely identical, open core/vm/instructions.go and see for yourself. The `ret` variable holds the `[]byte` array returned by DELEGATECALL. Maybe you can write a small part of your contract in assembly, so you call DELEGATECALL and catch this return value. This return value is put in memory at  `outOffset` position.

Comment: I think this `ret` variable indicates if the processing of the called function was successful.

Comment: no, `ret` is the output returned from the EVM. If there was any error it returns the `error`. This output is encoded according to the ABI. If you call abi.Unpack() on `ret` you will get the value according to its type. For example, all integers are stored in 32 bytes arrays,  all strings have first string length and then string data follows, and so on...