# Delegatecall require statement does not cause an abortion in any way

Tags: solidity, blockchain, delegatecall

This is a sequel to a [previous question of mine](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52766/synchronous-call-of-external-contract-function-in-solidity/52772#52772).

I want to implement a validation function (e.g. for passwords) within a central contract, that could be used by other contracts. It is important to notice, that this validation also considered the address of the caller. Therefore it needs to be called by `delegatecall` in order to access the actual caller through `msg.sender`. Since I cannot receive values when calling a function by `delegatecall` call (see my previous request), my new attempt is to abort processing by using several `require` statements within the validation function. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work, even if I force a `require` abortion.

```
contract Caller {

 function doSomething(address _callee, string _text) public {
   _callee.delegatecall(
                     bytes4(keccak256("validate(string)")), _text));

 /* further process if text is valid */
 }
}

contract Callee {

 function validate(string _text) public view {
  /* validity check */
  require(false);
 }
}
```

Even in the above example code, where I force an abortion, `doSomething` finished successfully. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delagetcall` will return false if it fails, you are not handling the returned value, you could do:

```
require(_callee.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("validate(string)")), _text)));
```

hope this helps

Comment: As a note for the OP, this is a Solidity thing. The opcode itself works the same as the call/callcode opcode, in that they all push a failure/success state to the stack, and whether or not to bubble up the failure is up to the calling code. Solidity, by default, does this "bubbling" when contracts are called high level with their ABI (`transfer` also bubbles up on failure), but it doesn't do it when you do low level calls like `delegatecall` and `call` like in the OP.

Comment: When I do it this way (`require(contract.delegatecall...`), the call will fail, when I try to access any property of the called contract. Is the reason for this, that the code is called from the calling storage?

Comment: Are you talking about the example in your question? it will always fail because you have `require(false)`, but I am guessing this is not what you mean. Please share the code you are referring  to.

Comment: I did some testing and found out, that it is indeed a problem of the scope. Let's say I have a public uint as a property of the called contract, that is set by the function that is called with `delegatecall`. Before the `delegatecall` the value is 0 and afterwards it is still 0 because it is another scope. When I call the same function without `delegatecall`, the value will change.